# Evaluate the integral $\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx$

Tags: integration

My friend asked me ot evaluate the integral:
$$\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx$$
And he gave me the hint: substitute $u = -x$. And so I did that, but I can't seem to get any farther than that. Could someone please provide some hints and help as to how to evaluate this challenging integral?

**EDIT:** Another hint he gave me was the split the integral into 2 integrals, one from $-2$ to $0$ and the other from $0$ to $2$, and again, I have tried this and I get stuck.

Comment: Just in case you're interested in where your friend got the integral, it can be found [here](https://sumo.stanford.edu/pdfs/smt2014/calculus-problems.pdf), and the solution to all ten problems in the last link can be found [here](https://sumo.stanford.edu/pdfs/smt2014/calculus-solutions.pdf).

Comment: @recursiverecursion I saw that, just what exactly is SMT?

Comment: it's a math competition run by Stanford. There are some pretty good questions on most of the exams.

Comment: @recursiverecursion thank for that link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral of $f(x)$ from $-2$ to $2$ is always the same as the integral of $f(-x)$ from $-2$ to $2$, so the integral is the same as
$$\int_{-2}^2 {1 + x^2 \over 1 + 2^{-x}}\,dx$$
Multiplying the numerator and denominator by $2^x$ gives
$$= \int_{-2}^2 {2^x (1 + x^2) \over 1 + 2^x}\,dx$$
Adding this to the orginal expression, twice the integral is equal to
$$\int_{-2}^2 {1 + x^2 \over 1 + 2^x}\,dx + \int_{-2}^2 {2^x (1 + x^2) \over 1 + 2^x}\,dx$$ 
$$= \int_{-2}^2 {(1 + 2^x)(1 + x^2) \over 1 + 2^x}\,dx$$
$$= \int_{-2}^2 ({1 + x^2})\,dx$$
$$= {28\over 3}$$
Hence the original integral is half that, or ${\displaystyle {14 \over 3}}$.

Comment: Great answer, thank-you!

Answer (score 10):

Hint:

$$\frac1{1+2^x} + \frac1{1+2^{-x}} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$I=\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx$$ we split it into two integrals
$$I_1=\int_{-2}^{0} \frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx$$
and
$$I_2=\int_{0}^{2} \frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx$$
On $I_1$ use the substitution $u=-x$. Proceed by setting $I=I_1 +I_2$ and applying the hint given by Ron Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting yields $$\int_{2}^{-2}-\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^{-x}},$$ which we can add to the original integral to get $$\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx + \int_{2}^{-2}-\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^{-x}} = \int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x} + \frac{1+x^2}{1+2^{-x}} = \int_{-2}^{2}1+x^2 = \frac{28}{3},$$ so our original integral is half that, which is $\displaystyle{\frac{14}{3}}$.